# Transpose part of a range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have text in cells in a vertical layout. I want to transpose them so that I have speaker next to their text (horizontally)
Transposing the whole range does not work.
[image: data]

I have 3 speakers but a lot of rows so can't do it manually. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(
     vlookup(
        sequence(roundup(counta(G6:G)/2),2,row(G6)),
        {row(G6:G),G6:G},
        2,
        0
     )
)
```